# Im using javascript and I have some questions about security

Tags: javascript, php

I'm learning to use LAMP stack but now im using javascript and I have some questions

Is there any security thread related to this kind of scripts:

Let's say there is a script

- that modifies the input values ​​of a form
- or maybe animations for a carousel of images
- or show or hide an image
- or a confirmation message like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function delete() {
    return window.confirm( 'Are you sure?' );
  }
</script>
```

Is there any security 
threat using that kind of things?
Or security is only compromised when I enter data without validating and sanitizing in my server

Im asking because I always read XSS are related to javascript. 
Also Im using the session variables of php, I read that javascript can steal those, how can I prevent that?
Is there any kind of threat that attacks my page without the information being sent to my server?
Just with validating and sanitizing and escaping i'm already safe?.
Im learning on my own.

Any article or book you know that explains these things, I would appreciate it if you would share it with me. I have not found anything very specific for these doubts, especially that of stealing php sessions.

Comment: Your question is way too broad for this forum. But a few notes to help point you in the right direction. Enable http only cookies in php.ini and javascript can't read your cookie. Session data is server side so it's safe as long as you don't store data in a cookie. Any validation done in javascript must also be done server side as the user can change javascript freely.  To prevent XSS sanitize user entered data that is printed back to the screen using `htmlspecialchars($data)`.

Comment: I would suggest starting from reading about cookies and how they work. This will make you understand how server-side can be affected by the client-size.